# jupyter notebook: cannot create new file

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

System info:

- Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Release: 14.04 Codename: trusty
- (I already have python 2.7.11) Installing jupyter:

  - jupyter: sudo pip install jupyter

Problem:

- open terminal: jupyter notebook -> firefox opened up
- terminal information:

  - [I 21:20:20.182 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/shawn
  - [I 21:20:20.182 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
  - [I 21:20:20.182 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
  - [I 21:20:20.182 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
- Normal jupyter home page showed up
- Click "new" -> "python 2", only a **new blank page** showed up
- Home page of jupyter showed:

  - Creating Notebook Failed
  - An error occurred while creating a new notebook.
  - error

Comment: I solved the problem by re-installing the system.....

Comment: I also faced the same. There were suggestions like to remove tornado and install a lower version of tornado. Still didn't work. So uninstalled and reinstalled python. It worked